# NE555 monostable timer circuit restart timer when trigger grounded in between

Tags: timer, 555, delay

I had made an NE555 timer IC based delay circuit (monostable mode) which keeps output HIGH for 10 seconds when trigger pin is connected to ground momentarily. But what I want is if I ground trigger pin again (momentarily) within the ten seconds, it restart the ten-second timer i.e. start timer again from that moment and keep output pin HIGH for another ten seconds. Any way to do that?

Below is my circuit Diagram.

[image]

Update: actually i am trying to replace the Arduino in my motion sensing relay circuit. Arduino is programmed in such a way that if motion is detected it turns relay ON immediately and if motion is not there then turns relay OFF after 1 minute. Also if there is any motion detected within that minute then the timer restarts. I think using Arduino just for that is a waste. Please suggest.

Comment: Use a retriggerable one shot IF.  If you MUST use a 555, https://m8051.blogspot.com/2013/02/retriggerable-555-timing-circuit.html

Comment: Thanks I'll try that circuit. Its not necessarily to be a 555 timer ic if something other work then I'll be fine with that.